# How to create an ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions object to set some options?

Tags: c++, com, webview2

I am using WebView2 and I want to cerate an `ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions` object to pass it to `CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions`

My current code is:

```
CComPtr<ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions> spOptions;
if (!m_strAdditionalBrowserArguments.IsEmpty())
{
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr = spOptions.CoCreateInstance(LIBID_WebView2)))
    {
        spOptions->put_AdditionalBrowserArguments(strArgument);
    }
}

hr = CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(
    !m_strBrowserExecutableFolder.IsEmpty() ? m_strBrowserExecutableFolder : nullptr, strDataFolder, 
    spOptions,
    Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler>(this, &CWebView2Wnd::OnCreateEnvironmentCompleted).Get()
);
```

But when I call `spOptions.CoCreateInstance` I get the error `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG`.

And this is true

`LIBID_WebView2` is `26D34152-879F-4065-BEA2-3DAA2CFADFB8`, and the IID for `ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions` is `2FDE08A8-1E9A-4766-8C05-95A9CEB9D1C5`

Or do I have to implement the interface by myself and pass tis interface to the CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I must create the object with WRL

```
auto spOptions = Microsoft::WRL::Make<CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions>();
if (!m_strAdditionalBrowserArguments.IsEmpty())
{
    spOptions->put_AdditionalBrowserArguments(m_strAdditionalBrowserArguments);
}

hr = CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(
    !m_strBrowserExecutableFolder.IsEmpty() ? m_strBrowserExecutableFolder : nullptr, strDataFolder, 
    spOptions.Get(),
    Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler>(this, &CWebView2Wnd::OnCreateEnvironmentCompleted).Get()
);
```